# In react-table v7, how to prevent column resizing to original width when selecting from dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using a react-select dropdown for the filter, and if I resize the column, and then select an item from the dropdown, the column automatically reverts to the set width for that column. The table works otherwise, just can't figure out how to prevent the column from resizing on click.

I've tried to prevent actions on click in the dropdown, which didn't work. These are also all of the imports from react-table we're using. I can't share the code because of my job though

````
  useTable,
  useSortBy,
  useFlexLayout,
  useFilters,
  usePagination,
  TableInstance,
  Row,
  useResizeColumns,
  useGlobalFilter,```
````